# Using switch-case in manipulating radio button values

Tags: jquery

I have this code that gets the values of the selected radio buttons and is supposed to tally them using a switch-case, then find out which has the highest value. However I am stuck in the switch statement as whenever the value goes inside it, it turns into NaN or undefined. I have tried to use parseInt, but still, whenever it goes inside the switch-case, it ruins the value I have got.

Here is the JS:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {  
    var choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5, choice6;

    if (($("input[name='qa1']:checked").length == "0")){
        alert("ANSWER ALL QUESTIONS!");
    }

    else{
        var answer1 = parseInt($("input[name='qa1']:checked").val());

        switch(answer1){
            case 1: choice1++; 
                    break;
            case 2: choice2++;
                    break;
        }
        alert(choice1);
//Closing braces
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="a_choice" id="a1" >
        <img src="img/q1-1.jpg" class="a_image" alt=" "/>
        <input type="radio" class="button" id="btn1" name="qa1" value="1">
        <label for="btn1"></label>
    </div>
<div class="a_choice" id="a2" >
        <img src="img/q1-2.jpg" class="a_image" alt=" "/>
        <input type="radio" class="button" id="btn2" name="qa1" value="2">
        <label for="btn2"></label>
    </div>
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="View Result" />
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is because you have to assign values like:

```
var choice1=0, choice2=0, choice3=0, choice4=0, choice5=0, choice6=0;
```

You have not assigning values to variables but increasing them that's why they showing you `NAN`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8gu3y/)

Comment: Hi Manwal! I have tried initializing the values of the choice variables, but still, whenever it goes inside the switch-case, it spits out NaN or undefined.

Comment: Thanks, Manwal! It turns out I removed the parseInt when I initiated the choice variables that's why it kept turning into NaN.